# Практические недостатки JSF 2

Tags: jsf, java

Сейчас выбираю framework для корпоративной web-системы. Выбор необходимо сделать между JSF 2.1 (PrimeFaces) и ZK 5. До этого в серьезном проекте JSF не использовал, по этому не знаю его реальных недостатков.

Из прочтенных отзывов о JSF складывается крайне негативное впечатление. Очень часто на форумах ругают JSF (не знаю насколько обоснованно). Хотя, читая tutorial-ы мне JSF 2 очень понравился. Возможно это касается только ***hello world*** приложений, а в реальном проекте с ним будет куча проблем.

Вопрос: какие недостатки вы отметили во время работы с JSF 2.

Comment: я jsf никогда не использовал, но изучал. основные недостатки это большой размер сесии, откуда дополнительная нагрузка на сервер для их хранения, откуда - непродолжительность сессии. получается что vkontakte и facebook с его использованием писать не стоит а вот небольшой интернет магазин можно